# Using multiple interfaces in Golang

Tags: go, design-patterns, interface

I'm learning Golang and as an exercise in using interfaces I'm building a toy program. I'm having some problem trying to use a type that "should implement" two interfaces - one way to solve that in C++ and Java would be to use inheritance(there are other techniques, but I think that is the most common). As I lack that mechanism in Golang, I'm not sure how to proceed about it. Below is the code:

```
var (
    faces = []string{"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"}

    suits = []string{"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"}
)

type Card interface {
    GetFace() string
    GetSuit() string
}

type card struct {
    cardNum int
    face    string
    suit    string
}

func NewCard(num int) Card {
    newCard := card{
        cardNum: num,
        face:    faces[num%len(faces)],
        suit:    suits[num/len(faces)],
    }

    return &newCard
}

func (c *card) GetFace() string {
    return c.face
}

func (c *card) GetSuit() string {
    return c.suit
}

func (c *card) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s%s ", c.GetFace(), c.GetSuit())
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

- I would like to hide my struct type and only export the interface so that the clients of the code use only the *"Card"* interface
- I would like to have a string representation of the struct, hence the implementation of the interface with the *"String()"* method in order to be able to call *"fmt.Println()"* on instantiations of my struct

The problem comes when I'm trying to use a new card though the "Card" interface and also trying to get the string representation. I cannot pass the interface as the parameter of the implementation of the *"String()"* method as there is a compiler error which is related to the addressability of an interface at the core language level(still digging through that documentation). The very simple example of testing exposes the issue:

```
func TestString(t *testing.T) {
    card := NewCard(0)
    assert.EqualValues(t, "AceHearts ", card.String(), " newly created card's string repr should be 'AceHearts '")
}
```

The compiler tells me, for good reason, that *"card.String undefined (type card has no field or method string)"*. I could just add the *"String()"* method to my *"Card"* interface, but I do not find that to be clean: I have other entities implemented with the same model and I would have to add that redundancy everywhere; there is already an interface with that method.

What would be a good solution for the above issue that I'm having?

**Edit:**(to address some of the very good comments)

- I do not expect to have another implementation of the *Card* interface; I'm not sure I grasp why would I want to do that, that is change the interface
- I would like to have the *Card* interface to hide away implementation details and for the clients to program against the interface and not against the concrete type
- I would like to always have access to the String() interface for all clients of the "card struct" instantiations(including the ones instantiated via the Card interface). I'm not interested in having clients only with the String interface. In some other languages this can be achieved by implementing both interfaces - multiple inheritance. I'm not saying that is good or wrong, or trying to start a debate about that, I'm just stating a fact!
- My intent is to find out if the language has any mechanism to fulfill those requirements simultaneously. If that is not possible or maybe from the point of view of the design the problem should be tackled in a different manner, then I'm ready to be educated
- Type assertions are very verbose and explicit and would expose implementation details - they have their places but I do not think they are appropriate in the situation I have

Comment: You could [type assert](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) your obj to make it a Stringer.

Comment: *"I would like to hide my struct type and only export the interface so that the clients of the code use only the "Card" interface"* -- That and the desire to use a method that's not part of the `Card` interface is a contradiction that's causing you the problem. First you'll need to fix that contradiction, then proceeding should be easier.

Comment: There are several options, but works for different purposes. One is `type assert`, which should be consider as some kind of interface upgrade, like the new `fs.FS` is doing in stdlib; another is defining a total and clear interface between the client code and your code, which means adding `String()`; yet another is to have a function `formatCard(card Card) string` that accepts the interface and provides a util to do the operation on the abstraction - this should be use if you expect another implementation of `Card`.

Comment: You shouldn't be testing through the interface, but the concrete type directly. The test should be in the same package as `card`, so you can just create `*card` values (as opposed to `Card` values). You can consider adding an unexported `func newCard(num int) *card` to assist the tests.

Comment: @mkopriva I do not agree it's a contradiction. I do not know the language in details yet, but there should be a way, albeit requiring some modifications, to arrive at that concept.

Comment: @Peter Why shouldn't I be testing through the interface? Could you provide some insights and details there?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev I would have to do that every time I want to pass a Card interface instance to the fmt.Println(), which is too explicit and defends the purpose of implementing the interface in the first place.

Comment: @celavek: as noted by mkopriva, your original intent defeats itself. Either you want to restrict clients to only use methods of this interface, or you don't.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev that statement is trimming away the context of the question. The question was about the possibility to have those two requirements fulfilled. If your opinion is that it cannot be done, then please post an answer, but do not tell me that my intent is wrong or defeats itself. My intent is to find out if the language has any mechanism to fulfill  those requirements simultaneously. If that is not possible or maybe from the point of view of the design the problem should be tackled in a different manner, then please post an answer and educate me.

Comment: @celavek To clarify what others are trying to say, I would like to ask you a few questions: 1) Do you expect to have another implementation of `Card` interface? Or is the sole purpose of having an interface to hide away the implementation details? 2) Do you want the client *always* have access to a `String() string` method? If not, then in what situations would you expect the client want to access a `String() string` method? 3) Are there any situations you expect that *the client* only wants the `String() string` but *not* the other APIs?

Comment: Your test *tells* you that it wants a `*card` because it doesn't restrict itself to the interface. You can test through the interface but then you obviously have to stick to just the interface. Such interface tests are typically done to test invariants that are expected of all valid implementations (see [testing/iotest](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/iotest/) for some that the standard library provides). But these tests exist in addtion to tests for concrete types. Basically, you still want to verify that `*card` works correctly, even if `NewCard` decides to return a different concrete type.

Comment: By the way, in this specific case you don't even need access to the String method directly. The fmt package will check if it exists: `assert.EqualValues(t, "AceHearts ", fmt.Sprint(NewCard(0)))`

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the clarification. I was afraid that maybe testing against the interface was frowned upon in Golang that's why I asked. So testing both via the interface and via the concrete type would be actually advisable, if I read between the lines correctly :).

Comment: "**I would like to hide my struct type and only export the interface so that the clients of the code use only the "Card" interface**". Please don't do this.  This is a unfortunately common anti-pattern that does nothing useful and significantly hinders the usability of package documentation.

Comment: @Hymns For Disco As I was saying I'm learning the language. This is loose coupling and programming to an interface. Interface segregation principle at work. I'm not inclined to ignore that just because it hinders package documentation, as they are good, solid principles of class and object design. I was under the impression that Go encourages that from what I've experienced of the language so far, as interfaces seem to have an important and predominant role at language and standard lib level. Please explain why is that an anti-pattern. Do you have some documentation regarding that?

Comment: *"I would like to always have access to the String() interface for all clients of the "card struct" instantiations(including the ones instantiated via the Card interface). I'm not interested in having clients only with the String interface. In some other languages this can be achieved by implementing both interfaces - multiple inheritance."* -- I'm genuinely interested to know how you would make this work in those other languages without *explicitly* adding `String()` to `Card`'s method set, or *explicitly* have `Card` inherit `String()` from another interface. @celavek

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, that is not entirely correct in terms of what can be achieved with other languages and also in terms of expectations I guess. Other languages example was mentioned just because of habit, that is habit to write code in those other languages, and not necessarly because I think they have a superior way to express what I want. To some extent it's pretty much the same thing as the type assert in Go. Thank you for the comments, although I did not agree entirely with them they definitely contributed to the discussion and to my better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I should go over some prefacing points first:

- Interfaces in Go are not the same as interfaces in other languages.  You shouldn't assume that every idea from other languages should transfer over automatically. A lot of them don't.
- Go has neither classes nor objects.
- Go is not Java and Go is not C++. It's type system is significantly and meaningfully different than those languages.

---

### From your question:

> I would like to have the Card interface to hide away implementation details and for the clients to program against the interface and not against the concrete type

This is the root of your other problems.

As mentioned in the comments, I see this in multiple other packages and regard it as a particularly pesky anti-pattern.  First, I will explain the reasons why this pattern is "anti" in nature.

- Firstly and most pertinently, this point is proven by your very example. You employed this pattern, and it has resulted in bad effects.  As pointed out by mkopriva, it has created a contradiction which you *must* resolve.
- this usage of interfaces is contrary to their intended use, and you are not achieving any benefit by doing this.

Interfaces are Go's mechanism of polymorphism.  The usage of interfaces in parameters makes your code more versatile. Think of the ubiquitous `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`. They are fantastic examples of interfaces.  They are the reason why you can patch two seemingly unrelated libraries together, and have them just work.  For example, you can log to stderr, or log to a disk file, or log to an http response.  Each of these work exactly the same way, because [log.New](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#New) takes an `io.Writer` parameter, and a disk file, stderr, and http response writer all implement `io.Writer`.  To use interfaces simply to "hide implementation details" (I explain later why this point fails), does not add any flexibility to your code.  If anything, it is an abuse of interfaces by leveraging them for a task they weren't meant to fulfill.

### Point / Counterpoint

1. "Hiding my implementation provides better encapsulation and safety by making sure all the details are hidden."

- You are not achieving any greater encapsulation or safety. By making the struct fields unexported (lowercase), you have already prevented any clients of the package from messing with the internals of your struct.  Clients of the package can only access the fields or methods that you have exported.  There's nothing wrong with exporting a struct and hiding every field.

2. "Struct values are dirty and raw and I don't feel good about passing them around."

- Then don't pass structs, pass pointers to struct.  That's what you're already doing here.  There's nothing inherently wrong with passing structs.  If your type behaves like a mutable object, then pointer to struct is probably appropriate.  If your type behaves more like an immutable data point, then struct is probably appropriate.

3. "Isn't it confusing if my package exports `package.Struct`, but clients have to always use `*package.Struct`?  What if they make a mistake?  It's not safe to copy my struct value; things will break!"

- All you realistically have to do to prevent problems is make sure that your package *only returns* `*package.Struct` values.  That's what you're already doing here. A vast majority of the time, people will be using the short assignment `:=`, so they don't have to worry about getting the type correct.  If they do set the type manually, and the choose `package.Struct` by accident, then they will get a compilation error when trying to assign a `*package.Struct` to it.

4. "It helps to decouple the client code from the package code"

- Maybe.  But unless you have a realistic expectation that you have multiple existent implementations of this type, then this is a form of premature optimization (and yes it does have consequences).  Even if you *do* have multiple implementations of your interface, that's still not a good reason why you should actually *return* values of that interface.  A majority of the time it is still more appropriate to just return the concrete type. To see what I mean, take a look at the [`image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/) package from the standard library.

### When is it actually useful?

The main realistic case where making a premature interface *AND* returning it *might* help clients, is this:

- Your package introduces a second implementation of the interface

  - AND clients have statically and explicitly (not `:=`) used this data type in *their* functions or types
  - AND clients want to reuse those types or functions for the new implementation also.

Note that this wouldn't be a breaking API change even if you weren't returning the premature interface, as you're only **adding** a new type and constructor.

If you decided to only *declare* this premature interface, and still return concrete types  (as done in the `image` package), then all the client would likely need to do to remedy this is spend a couple minutes using their IDE's refactor tool to replace `*package.Struct` with `package.Interface`.

### It significantly hinders the usability of package documentation

Go has been blessed with a useful tool called Godoc. Godoc automatically generates documentation for a package from source.  When you export a type in your package, Godoc shows you some useful things:

- The type, all exported methods of that type, and all functions that return that type are organized together in the doc index.
- The type and each of its methods has a dedicated section in the page where the signature is shown, along with a comment explaining it's usage.

Once you bubble-wrap your struct into an interface, your Godoc representation is hurt. The methods of your type are no longer shown in the package index, so the package index is no longer an accurate overview of the package as it is missing a lot of key information.  Also, each of the methods no longer has its own dedicated space on the page, making it's documentation harder to both find and read. Finally it also means that you no longer have the ability to click the method name on the doc page to view the source code. It's also no coincidence that in many packages that employ this pattern, these de-emphasized methods are most often left without a doc comment, even when the rest of the package is well documented.

### In the wild

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/zserge/lorca

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io

In both cases we see a misleading package overview, along with a majority of interface methods being undocumented.

(Please note I have nothing against any of these developers; obviously every package has it's faults and these examples are cherry picked.  I'm also not saying that they had no justification to use this pattern, just that their package doc is hindered by it)

### Examples from the standard library

If you are curious about how interfaces are "intended to be used", I would suggest looking through the docs for the standard library and taking note of where interfaces are declared, taken as parameters, and returned.

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

https://golang.org/pkg/io/

https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/

https://golang.org/pkg/image/

Here is the only standard library example I know of that is comparable to the "interface hiding" pattern.  In this case, reflect is a very complex package and there are several implementations of `reflect.Type` internally.  Also note that in this case, even though it is necessary, no one should be happy about it because the only real effect for clients is messier documentation.

https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type

## tl;dr

This pattern will hurt your documentation, while accomplishing nothing in the process, except you might make it slightly quicker in very specific cases for clients to use parallel implementations of this type that you may or may not introduce in the future.

These interface design principles are meant for the benefit of the client, right?  Put yourself in the shoes of the client and ask: what have I really gained?

Comment: Absolutely awesome! Thank you for the thorough explanation. It definitely set me on the right path.

Comment: @celavek I'm glad it has shown some value to you.  If you are interested in the design philosophy of Go, including its deliberate departures from Java and C++, may I suggest [this talk](https://youtu.be/rFejpH_tAHM) by Rob Pike.  He has several great talks on YouTube that I come back to from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for but you could try embedding the other interface in Card interface as shown below.

```golang
type Printer interface {
    String() string
}

type Card interface {
    Printer // embed printer interface
    GetFace() string
    GetSuit() string
}
```

Comment: that is basically the same as adding the String method. I would have also to make that composition for each entity requiring that.

Answer (score 1):

Interface `Card` hasn't method `String`, it doesn't matter, that underlying type `card` have it, because method is hidden from you (unless you access it via reflection).
Adding `String() string` method to `Card` will solve problem:

```
type Card interface {
    GetFace() string
    GetSuit() string
    String()  string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The go language does not have [subtype polymorsphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping). Therefore, the pattern you want to achieve is not *encouraged* by the very foundations of the language. You may achieve this undesirable pattern by composing structs and interfaces, though.