# golang echo controller model

Tags: go, go-echo

I am getting the following error when trying to factory my controller:

> cannot use &(personController literal) (value of type
> *personController) as PersonController value in return statement: wrong type for method CreateNewPerson (have func(ctx
> github.com/labstack/echo/v4.Context) error, want func(ctx
> github.com/labstack/echo/v4.Context))

controller:

```
package controllers

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

type personController struct{}

var (
// services
)

type PersonController interface {
    CreateNewPerson(ctx echo.Context)
    GetPerson(ctx echo.Context)
}

func NewPersonController() PersonController {
    return &personController{}
}

func (*personController) CreateNewPerson(ctx echo.Context) error {
    return ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, "Hello")
}

func (*personController) GetPerson(ctx echo.Context) error {
    return ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, "Hello")
}
```

and in my main func ai got this error :

```
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    controller := controllers.NewPersonController()
    e.POST("/a", controller.CreateNewPerson)
}
```

> cannot use controller.CreateNewPerson (value of type func(ctx
> echo.Contex

Comment: Why have both a `personController` struct and `PersonController` interface?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I need to pass my mediator as a dependency
and then I thought of creating the mediator in the struct of the controller

this is bad ?

Can you help me?

Comment: As a side note, returning an interface is an anti-pattern: https://medium.com/@cep21/preemptive-interface-anti-pattern-in-go-54c18ac0668a

Comment: @TylerKropptt From what I understand in the article is it better to return structs and use interfaces in the parameters?

i'm new to go, i would be happy if u could give me an example.

Comment: Yes, that is a good general rule (though there could be exceptions).  You can also read my answer about a similar idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67133656/11424673)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface and struct implementation don't match. If you want your interface method's to match what's required by the echo framework then do this:

```golang
type PersonController interface {
    CreateNewPerson(ctx echo.Context) error
    GetPerson(ctx echo.Context) error
}
```

Comment: thank u, do you think this approach is better to have to instantiate a person controller to be able to call or just use a var without the interface?

like this personController.new ()
personController.get ()

Comment: I would probably just keep them as pure functions (e.g. not a method on a struct) if they don't have any dependencies as it keeps things simple

Comment: they will have dependencies like commandbus and validator, but I'm a little confused on how to do this.

Comment: If that is the case I would have a struct which has these dependencies in it, the methods can then "hang off" the struct. This article goes through different patterns for organising DB connections https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access but the same logic could be applied to other resources. I would just get something working and see what works best for your use case 