# Implementing an interface with a wider method signature

Tags: go

In Go, is there a way to implement an interface using a method, where the return type of the corresponding method in the implementation is a "wider than" the expected return type?

This is difficult to explain so here is an example. I get this error when running the below example code in Go Playground:

```
./prog.go:36:14: cannot use BirdImpl{} (type BirdImpl) as type Animal in argument to foo:
    BirdImpl does not implement Animal (wrong type for Move method)
        have Move() BirdMoveResult
        want Move() AnimalMoveResult
```

(where `BirdMoveResult` is "wider than" `AnimalMoveResult` because any implementation of `BirdMoveResult` is also an implementation of `AnimalMoveResult`)

```
package main

type (
    Animal interface {
        Move() AnimalMoveResult
    }
    Bird interface {
        Move() BirdMoveResult
    }
    AnimalMoveResult interface {
        GetDistance() int
    }
    BirdMoveResult interface {
        GetDistance() int
        GetHeight() int
    }
    BirdImpl struct{}
    BirdMoveResultImpl struct{}
)

// Some implementation of BirdImpl.Move
// Some implementation of BirdMoveResultImpl.GetDistance
// Some implementation of BirdMoveResultImpl.GetHeight

func foo(animal Animal) int {
    return animal.Move().GetDistance()
}

func main() {
    foo(BirdImpl{})  // This fails because BirdImpl doesn't implement Animal. My question is why not?
}
```

I understand that the `Move()` method signatures do not match completely because of the different return types, thus Go does not consider `BirdImpl` as an implementation of `Animal`. However, if Go compares the return types, any implementation of `BirdMoveResult` would also implement `AnimalMoveResult`. So, shouldn't `Move() BirdMoveResult` be an acceptable implementation for `Move() AnimalMoveResult` (and if not, why not)?

Edit: In the actual scenario, `Animal`, `AnimalMoveResult`, and `foo` are part of an external package. Within my own code, I want to be able to extend `AnimalMoveResult` with my own interface methods (as it's done in the example with `BirdMoveResult`), while still being able to make use of `foo` with using the extended interface.

Comment: Though I appreciate the effort to convey the problem, this type system looks really convoluted. Basically you have multiple redundant layers prying you away from the only thing of substance: `GetDistance()` (and `GetHeight()`, which is un-used).

Comment: In order for a type to satisfy an interface, it must implement all the methods defined in the interface *exactly as they are defined in the interface*.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco It seems redundant because it's an (over)simplified example of the issue I'm trying to communicate

Comment: @Adrian That's what I thought (and what the answers have helped to confirm), I guess my question is more about why Go does not support this type of interface matching/what limitations there are in trying to support it

Comment: One of the design goals of Go is to simplify type systems. Think of interfaces as the grease that makes different pieces work together more smoothly. It should be applied only in the right places, or else things will get quite messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kinds of problems are usually the result of:

- Premature interfaces
- Fake interfaces, or "bubble-wrapping" (see my rant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67133656/11424673))
- Parallel interfaces

Your error you have is most specifically related to the 3rd issue, but each is present in your example design here.

Good interfaces should convey (in their name and their method signatures) a set of behaviour. The name of the interface should be implied by method(s) it contains, as the name is simply supposed to capture the essence of that behaviour.

The only interface seemingly needed for this purpose is:

```golang
type Mover interface {
    Move() MoveResult
}
```

For MoveResult, you can do this (exchange float with int if you like):

```golang
type MoveResult struct {
    Distance, Height float64
}
```

This type can potentially function just fine as a struct, given the following assumptions:

- Move results are just data points (they don't need to be dynamic; you can set the values and leave them)
- "Extra" data like Height function properly with a zero value when it's not specified.

Now, implement the bird type:

```golang
type Bird struct {
    // some internal data
}

func (b *Bird) Move() MoveResult {
    // some movement calculations
    return MoveResult{Distance: howFar, Height: howHigh}
}
```

Now implement foo:

```golang
func foo(m Mover) float64 {
    return m.Move().Distance
}
```

Now use it in main:

```golang
func main() {
    foo(&Bird{})
}
```

Now we can add other kinds of `Mover`s to the program and use them with `foo` without issue.

---

Addressing your comment, where `Animal`, `AnimalMoveResult` and `foo` are all external and you can't modify them:

How I'm posing the problem with my understanding: There is this function `foo`, designed to accept an interface called `Animal`, which is characterized by how it returns an proprietary type. You want to use your type `Bird` as an `Animal`, but you can't fit all of the behaviour you want into that proprietary return type.

So how to resolve this?

Implement your own, wider return type

```golang
type birdMoveResult struct {
    // some internal data
}

func (r birdMoveResult) GetDistance() int {
    // get the distance
}

func (r birdMoveResult) GetHeight() int {
    // get the height
}
```

Now, implement the Bird type

```golang
type Bird struct {
    // some internal data
}

func (b *Bird) Move() AnimalMoveResult {
    var result birdMoveResult
    // calculate the move result
    return birdMoveResult
}
```

Notice that `Move` returns the `AnimalMoveResult` type, so now `Bird` will satisfy the `Animal` interface. We are able to do this because `birdMoveResult` satisfies the `AnimalMoveresult` type, so returning it here is legal.

The remaining issue is that `Bird`'s `Move` method narrows the wide interface, we've effectively lost that new functionality you added. In order to get it back while still satisfying the `Animal` interface, we can't change the `Move` method signature at all. Here are 2 possible workarounds.

1. When using your bird type, you can [type-assert](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) the result to gain access to the extra method

```golang
var b Bird
// ...
height := b.Move().(birdMoveResult).GetHeight()
```

2. Add a new method to `Bird` that returns the wider type, leaving the existing `Move` with the same signature

```golang
func (b *Bird) MoveFull() birdMoveResult {
    var result birdMoveResult
    // calculate the move result
    return birdMoveResult
}

func (b *Bird) Move() AnimalMoveResult {
    return b.MoveFull()
}
```

```golang
height := b.MoveFull().GetHeight()
```

Either of these will work, it's mostly a matter of preference.

Comment: Thank you for explaining and trying to simplify all this. What if I told you that `Animal`, `AnimalMoveResult`, and `foo` where from a different package (that I couldn't edit)? Yet, I still need to expand on the `AnimalMoveResult` to define additional methods which are more specific, and call function `foo`. 

All of the interface names are only for the example and are irrelevant (you can imagine other names so that they do describe a set of behaviour, but the structure of the code is still the same).

Comment: @DavidL Updated answer

Comment: I see... This is helpful, thanks! I'll add the extra details from my comment to my original question later on

Answer (score 2):

> In Go, is there a way to implement an interface using a method, where the return type of the corresponding method in the implementation is a "wider than" the expected return type?

No. Methods signatures must match literally. Go has no notion of co- or contravariance.

Answer (score 1):

Go's type system uses type name match. This would fail even if the same interface is returned with a different type name.

However, you can declare the method to satisfy the interface, but return a wider implementation that can be type-asserted.