# When should we utilize method receiver / argument during Go interface implementation?

Tags: go, interface

So from what I understood, in order to achieve polymorphism in Go, we want to utilize the type receiver and using the value from it during the interface implementation.

In that case, when should we utilize the method parameter instead receiver during interface implementation? from my point of view, making an interface with rigid / lots of signature will make the interface less useful.

assuming I have this struct, interface and implementation

```
type BankAccount struct {
    UserId uint64, 
    AccountName string, 
    BankName string
}
type IBankAccount interface { 
    CheckBankAccount()
}
func (b *BankAccount) CheckBankAccount() { 
// do something that require b.UserId, b.AccountName and b.BankName
}
    
//we call it like this 
b:= BankAccount{UserId: 1, AccountName: "123", BankName: "some-bank"}
b.CheckBankAccount()
```

is it better than this one?

```
type BankAccount struct {}
type IBankAccount interface { 
    CheckBankAccount(userId uint64, accountName string, bankName string)
}

func (b *BankAccount) CheckBankAccount(userId uint64, accountName string, bankName string) { 
// do something that require userid accountname and bank name
}
  //calling
b:= BankAccount{}
b.CheckBankAccount(1, "123", "some-bank")
```

but it looks like the 2nd example, the interface implementation is more like common function (?)

On the other hand, the 1st example seems to hide a lot of detail and require future code reader to read what parameter is being used inside the implementation. Is that what the abstraction should be or I misunderstood the concept?

Comment: The first interface is basically useless as an interface.

Comment: does that mean we should balancing out utilizing both value from receiver and argument? as in 2nd example but with BankName in the struct (for example)?
@HymnsForDisco

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand the relationship between struct and interface. The purpose of the interface is describe a complete, useful behaviour through a set of methods. That's why the first one is "almost useless". The only method takes no parameters, and returns no values. From a practical point of view, it's not clear how the concept of a "back account" is completely and usefully described when it doesn't take or yield any data.

Comment: It's maybe a pet peeve of mine but this may be an example of "bubble wrapping" where concrete data type is obscured by an unnecessary/premature interface, leading to convoluted implementation and abstraction https://stackoverflow.com/a/67133656/11424673

Comment: oh sorry that's completely on my bad about returning no values. Forgot to put it because it's from actual project so gotta remove something. The CheckBankAccount will return struct containing account detail about whether the bank account is usable or not.

Comment: In that case, I think the first option is more appropriate (with the addition of the return value).

Comment: consider reading about private discrete interface. it helps decouple the design.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a confusion of a couple of concepts here.

An interface won't have any fields, but types implementing the interface will. And for a type implementing an interface, it's perfectly fine (and quite common) for the method implementation to use the underlying type's fields.

Adjusting your example, the common way would be something like:

```
// IBankAccount is an interface different types can implement.
type IBankAccount interface { 
    CheckBankAccount()
}

// BankAccount is a concrete bank account type.
type BankAccount struct {
    UserId uint64, 
    AccountName string, 
    BankName string
}

// CheckBankAccount makes BankAccount implement the IBankAccount
// interface.
func (b *BankAccount) CheckBankAccount() { 
    // It's fine to use b's fields here!!
}
```

The key part is how the interface is *used*. Here's a function that accepts a parameter that implements the `IBankAccount` interface; the compiler will let you pass any type into `someFunc`, as long as this type implements the interface. `someFunc` can then call the interface's methods.

```
func someFunc(b IBankAccount) {
  // ...
  b.CheckBankAccount()
  // ...
}
```

We can call `someFunc` with:

```
b := BankAccount{...}
someFunc(b)
```

Obviously, you could create a different type e.g. `FancyAccount`, with its own fields, and if it implements `CheckBankAccount` it also implements `IBankInterface` and can therefore be passed into `someFunc`.

---

The signature of your interface methods is up to your specific application. Typically, interfaces try to be as simple as possible - few methods, and the methods have few parameters. Take a look at some of the standard library interfaces for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. If I get you right, if the interface should be simple, then I suppose interface is more suited to define behavior instead of defining the entire function? so instead of having just CheckBackAccount implementing concrete implementation, we can decompose it by utilizing multiple interface to define the behaviour of CheckBankAccount, correct?

Comment: @sswastioyono18: it really depends on the particular case, and it's hard to talk in abstracts. Your example is a toy, so it would be better to discuss a real-world interface.